# How can I sort Evernote notes by importance?

Tags: evernote

I have a notebook called "To-do lists" in Evernote. Each note is a separate list of related things.

Some lists are more important than others. I want the most important list to always appear on top of the notebook.

Currently, I prepend a number to the title and sort by title.

```
1 - Very urgent things
2 - Moderately urgent things
3 - Not important but do eventually
```

When I sort by title, they automatically get sorted by importance, and if I forget to assign an importance to a note, it ends up at the bottom. Perfect, except I don't want to pollute my titles with the number.

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort your urgent notes by tags. Give your notes the tags #1, #2, #3 in order of urgency. It seems to work with the hash symbol included as well. Then enable Snippet View or Card View (View, Snippet View or Card View). In the drop-down menu at the top right of the List/Card View column you can chose ‘Sort notes by’ then select ‘Tags’. Don’t check ‘Reverse Sort Order’ at the bottom of that menu.

Now your notes are sorted by #1, #2, #3 tags and not by note title. The one drawback is that this is now the default sort order for all your notebooks not just your ‘To-do lists’ notebook. You may have to change back to your usual sort order once you leave your To-do lists notebook.